# Nodemon Inspect address already in use when refresh with vscode debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, nodemon, inspect

I am debugging a node application in Visual Studio, so I have to attach create a new configuration in launch.json:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Debug API",
  "remoteRoot": "/workspaces/telehealth/projects/api",
  "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/projects/api",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "port": 9229,
  "restart": true,
  "address": "localhost",
  "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
}
```

And the script in package.json is

```
nodemon -e js,gql --watch dist --watch typeDefs --delay 500ms --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./dist/index.js
```

That works fine the first time, but when I save a file and the server restarts, it fails with the classical error **address already in use** because the debugger is running.
I have to turn off the debugger, wait 5 seconds and then save the file to restart the server. After that, I have to start the debugger again.

There should be a way to restart without stopping the running process to debug, but I couldn't find nothing

Comment: Did you try a longer --delay?

Comment: Yes, there is it in the command, but while the debugger still running, the port will be in use to nodemon